# Jmeter plugin perfMon not listening to localhost

Tags: jmeter

In jMeter, I have installed perfMon plugin that listens to 4444 port successfully. My application runs on localhost:8080. It seems when I give default http  port as 8080 as per the attached image, api works fine but no graph for perfMon metric plugin. But when I give http default port as 4444, perfMon shows graph but API fails giving 404.

How can I run both my application in localhost:8080 and listen to same port using server agent/ perfMon agent (which runs on 4444 port)?[image]

FYI. I need to monitor the tomcat server(where my tested application resides).For that I have installed server-agent in my tomcat server.Edited jmeter.properties like below: remote_hosts=localhost:4444
I am running my application in tomcat of docker container and I have installed perfMon server agent locally at my system /opt directory. Does it has to installed somewhere specific directory ?
In server agent console, I am getting error

```
ERROR   2018-03-09 13:25:19.126 [kg.apc.p] (): Error getting metric
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: No such process: 728
    at org.hyperic.sigar.SigarProxyCache.invoke(SigarProxyCache.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getProcCpu(Unknown Source)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.CPUProcMetric.getValue(CPUProcMetric.java:35)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.getMetricsLine(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:114)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processSenders(PerfMonWorker.java:280)
    at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.run(PerfMonWorker.java:243)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

as I have set the pid in metric parameter as follows(my tomcat pid =728 in docker)[image]
every time after hitting API in jMeter, it is saying client disconnted
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. When it says "client disconnected", it is not an error, it is info. I forgot to change pid in metric parameter whenever I run the server.